# How to keep flashlight light on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I created an app, it makes camera flashlight light on to simulate real Torch. But once the Lock screen is on, the flashlight can't stay too long, a few seconds later, the light will off. Is there have any way to keep flashlight light on always?

P.S I found some app on Microsoft App Marketplace, they did this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will allow your app to continue to run when the lock screen is activated:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.applicationidledetectionmode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[Example](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Run_Windows_Phone_application_under_lock_screen)